# Is there a way to keep an audio player playing consistently whenever i switch pages on a joomla website?

Tags: html, web, audio, backend, joomla2.5

So i made this website using joomla 2.5 and my client asked me to add an audio player to the website, so i added an audio player plugin using power.io and it worked fine, except for when i click on any link to navigate the website to another page the music stops and it resets the changes i made on the audio player (progress of the track, which track is playing, the shuffle button..), so i need to press the play button again each time i'm on a new page.
Tell me if there's a better way to implement this.

Comment: You should definitely not be using Joomla2.5 anymore; you are long overdue for an upgrade.  If you are doing Joomla development, please extend your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @mickmackusa i know, the thing is that this is an old project.